# How to quickly pair a guest's Wii remote?

Tags: nintendo-wii, controllers, wiimote

Every time my friends are over with their own pair of Wii remotes, I have to do this hit-or-miss pairing dance over and over again. I'm not sure what the "correct" way of doing this is, and the manual is kind of vague.

So, what's the easiest (fastest) way of (temporarily) using a guest's Wii Remote on my Wii?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The easiest way is this:

Edit: Here's the text from the manual.  Any use of bold, numbers, and bullets are from the actual manual text.

Wii Operations Manual - System Setup, page 20

> **ONE TIME MODE** - This mode allows you to temporarily use your remote on
> a console other than your own or to
> use a friends remote on your console.
> **It does not delete the Standard Mode setting stored in the remote.**

Wii Operations Manual - System Setup, page 21

> One Time Mode Synchronization
>
> NOTE: This mode temporarily removes
> the Standard Mode synchronization
> setup for all remotes until the power
> of the Wii console is turned off. When
> the power is turned on again, the
> Standard Mode settings will return.
>
> 1. Press the HOME Button on a remote that is synchronized with the console.
> 2. Select the Wii Remote Settings option from the Home Button menu, then
>    select the Reconnect option.
> 3. Press the 1 and 2 Buttons simultaneously on the remote that you
>    want to synchronize with the console.
>    **The order in which you synchronize remotes will set the player order for
>    multiplayer games.**
> 4. The Player LEDs will blink during the syncing process. When the
>    blinking stops, the connection is
>    complete.See diagram at right for description of what the blinking indicates.

Next to said diagram:

> During the syncing process, the number of LEDs that blink will show the battery life of the remote that is being synchronized.
>
> After the syncing process, LED that is lit shows the player number for that remote.
>
> **NOTE: One Time Mode synchronization is temporary. The Wii Remote will lose this synchronization under the following conditions:**
>
> - When your turn off the console by pressing the Power Button on either the remote or the console.
> - When starting up a game or Channel from the Wii Menu.
> - When returning to the Wii Menu after exiting from a game or Channel.
> - When you select Reset on the HOME Menu Screen.
> - When you press the Reset button on the front of the console.

Comment: This isn't what he's asking. He's asking how to reconnect wiimotes that aren't paired with the current system. Your proposal will only work with remotes paired with the current system.

Comment: @McKay: When I get home, I'll pull out my Wii manual and quote the part of it that says you can temporarily pair remotes not paired with the system this way.

Comment: I want to say that I've tried this specifically, but I might be mistaken.

Comment: @McKay: The Wii Operations Manual - System Setup, pages 20-21 says you're wrong.  I've quoted the appropriate sections in my answer now.

Comment: I've been using this method for a while now, and it usually works. It's a bit hit-or-miss sometimes, and I can't figure out if your supposed to hold the buttons until the remote is paired, or if you can just press and let go.

Answer (score 1):

The way that seems to work best for me when pairing wiimotes (or using the "reconnect" option to change the order) is this:

Pair each wiimote one-at-a-time in the order you want. Have each player hold down the 1+2 buttons until that wiimote pairs. Then have the next player, etc. It seems to take a few seconds for each wiimote.

I wish it was a bit smoother than that.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I did to my remote and it works perfect http://howtofixstuff.blogspot.ca/2013/08/how-to-fix-wii-remote-sync.html

Comment: Hi franca and welcome to Arqade! Could you please summarise the information contained in that link in your answer, in case the link goes down? Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

Take the battery back off the controller and open the small flap under the disc slot on the front of the Wii (where the SD card goes).

Hit the red button on both of them at the same time.